# Can't Loop all urls, CURL and output them to corresponding file

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing this script in my mac to loop all the urls in temp file and curl each of them and save each of them as different names.

```
for i in `cat temp`; do echo $i; n= awk -F/ '{printf $4}' <<< $i; curl $i -o  $n.json; done
```

But it's never run as expected. they always output to file ".json". I'm not sure what wrong with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular solution, there are two issues. The first is that there is no need to use cat for a loop and also, you have not expanded the awk command into the variable n. The code should be written as:

```
while read i; 
do 
  echo "$i"; 
  n="$(awk -F/ '{printf $4}' <<< "$i")"; 
  curl "$i" -o  "$n.json"; 
done < temp
```

Awk can also be used as more of a complete solution:

```
awk -F\/ '{ print "curl "$0" -o "$4".json" }' temp | bash
```

Process the whole file with awk and construct the curl command before piping to bash for execution.